# How to get a nicely formatted JUnit report out of a Maven test run?

Tags: maven, junit, report

I have:

- a pom.xml which includes junit 4.4, log4j 1.2, and maven-surefire-plugin
- Some Scala tests with `@RunWith(classOf[JUnitRunner])` and FunSpec

To run it, I do `maven clean test` etc.

I can generate Surefire HTML reports with a `surefire-report` Maven switch, but they're not very detailed and I don't think they conform to standard JUnit reports?

Any hints on how I can get a JUnit report output with a nice format (e.g. HTML + CSS)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [surefire-report:report](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-surefire-report-plugin/report-mojo.html) and [surefire-report:report-only](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-surefire-report-plugin/report-only-mojo.html) goals will generate HTML report for Maven test execution. As part of Maven site generation it could be further styled using one of the [skins](http://maven.apache.org/skins/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

You may try Allure Reports which can generate a report website .

A sample project [here](https://github.com/sarkershantonu/Automation-Getting-Started/tree/master/AllureJunit)